# How should I configure eslint so that all if and for statements are bracketed and newline

Tags: javascript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I don't like the following style of code

```js
const flag = Math.random() > 0.5;

if (flag) console.log('A');
else console.log('B');

for (let index = 0; index < 999; index++) console.log(index);
```

I hope to restrict their behavior through eslint, so that if statements and for statements must have **parentheses** and **newlines**

```js
const flag = Math.random() > 0.5;

if (flag) {
  console.log('A');
} else {
  console.log('B');
}

for (let index = 0; index < 999; index++) {
  console.log(index);
}
```

How should I configure my eslint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curly rule is what you are searching for:

https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/curly